# Responsive design for tables

Tags: responsive-design

I am new to responsive frameworks and I want to know if tables in an existing html file can be added the responsiveness.

If tables cannot be done so, how should tabular data be displayed for it to be "responsive" to the device size.

Comment: http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2

Answer (score 0):

if you put table in the following div; user will be able to scroll left and right.

```
<div style="width:100%; overflow:auto">

</div>
```